# Setting up cronjob in Wordpress automatically without visitors

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cron-task, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing a plugin that needs a piece of code to run every hour even if no visitors have been on the site that day.

The goal is to have a plugin that i can activate and that just works without asking the clients to set up a cron-job inside of their server settings.

From what i understand wp-cron is not an option here since it only activates on page visit, i would love to hear some advice on this!

I hope i provided enough info, thanks in advance!

Comment: Best way to achieve a solid cron job, is via the C-panel or the WHM panel, put still, could you please provide more information about the problem? or include the code you want to debug. What we need in order to help you, is a specific problem. Information about wp cron jobs can be found here https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-view-and-control-wordpress-cron-jobs/

Comment: You cannot have a native / real cronjob without setting up one.

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis I dont think you read my question right, i do not want to set up a cronjob in any server panels or anything, the goal is to have the cron-job set up when the plugin activates. I have no code yet as im clueless to how this would be achieved

Comment: @DanielW. Thanks for the response, would there be any other kind of solution to this?

Comment: Tell the ppl who use your plugin how to setup a real cronjob (edit `crontab`, `crontab -e`, edit `/etc/cron.d/wordpress-plugin.conf`, etc...)

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis Please read properly. wp-cron only triggers when users visit.

Comment: @DanielW. So how i envisioned my plugin is not possible without having the users set up a cronjob. Thanks for anwsering the question.

Comment: There are free services that allow you to trigger a wp cronjob from outside by visiting your page every X minutes. (Search for free cronjob online)

Comment: Having your own bot but you have to know the address where the plugin is installed. Also there are other problems like blocking your bot or restricted access or other security measures. I dont see a problem if a plugin user have to setup before use it. Many plugins require some sort of setup.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use native cron. The native cron job is:

```
wget -q -O - https://example.org/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Set it to run either every 5, 15, or 30 min depending on amount of server resources you have. I recommend a minimum of 30 min. Make sure to replace https://example.org with your domain and protocol (ssl or non ssl).

If you are using the command line (crontab) and/or the cron service doesn't allow you to change the time automatically. This is the full cron job:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - 'https://example.org/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Replace 5 by the interval you want the cron to run (every 30 min, every 15 min etc.). In this example, the cron is ran every 5 min.